# Validate/Authorise cvv number from Stripe without charge in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, stripe-payments, payment

Anyone please confirm how to validate/authorise cvv number of your credit/debit card from Stripe without charging the card? I am using Stripe to create card token but that did not validate cvv. I am building a custom UI to add my payment details but I need to validate whether card details (cvv number) are correct or not without charging it. Below is the function I am using but that did not worked.

```
func isValidCard(cardNumber: String?, month: UInt, year: UInt, cvv: String?) -> Bool {
    
        let params = STPCardParams()
        params.number = cardNumber
        params.expMonth = month
        params.expYear = year
        params.cvc = cvv
        if STPCardValidator.validationState(forCard: params) == .valid {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to check that the CVV length match the card brand, you could simply use [`validationState(forCVC:cardBrand:)`](https://stripe.dev/stripe-ios/docs/Classes/STPCardValidator.html#/c:@M@Stripe@objc(cs)STPCardValidator(cm)validationStateForCVC:cardBrand:).

To check that the CVV is valid without actually charging the user, then you need to save the customer’s card with a SetupIntent. You can do so in two main ways:

- Use the Payment Sheet as explained [in this detailed guide](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse)
- Or create a SetupIntent on your backend and then confirm it on the frontend with [`STPSetupIntentConfirmParams`](https://stripe.dev/stripe-ios/docs/Classes/STPSetupIntentConfirmParams.html) while passing the card details

Note that Stripe cannot guarantee that the CVV check will be available [as explained  here](https://support.stripe.com/questions/check-if-a-card-is-valid-without-a-charge).